# How to annotate a variable in Vue as a Vue component when using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm using VueJS and Typescript and I am not using Class-Style Vue Components.

Say I have the following Vue component.

```
<template>
    <my-component ref="component"/>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import MyComponent from "@/components/my-component.vue";

export default Vue.extend({
    components: {
        MyComponent,
    },
    methods: {
        async someMethod() {
            // How do I annotate the following component variable as type "MyComponent"?
            const component = this.$refs["component"];
            console.log(component.$props);
        },
    },
});
</script>
```

**How do I annotate the `component` variable in the `someMethod` method properly so that the Typescript compiler is aware of properties like `$props` etc.?**

The following (which was my initial instinct) does not work.

```
const component: MyComponent = this.$refs["component"];
```

Answer (score 0):

in vue+vscode ecosystem, now typescript cannot  infer type from template declaration. (maybe it will be)

and for $refs[xxx]:

Type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]' is not assignable to type 'Vue'.

you can use type assertions instead:

const component = this.$refs["component"] as typeof MyComponent;

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I receive the following error: `'MyComponent' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof MyComponent'`

Comment: @user8888 , u are right.  `as  typeof MyComponent` is right ; or  `as Vue` instead . ?